Android BLE requestMtu() doesn't seem to work
Introduction
I am involved in developing an Android application that controls a physical device via BLE.
One of the features of the app is to send a large amount of data. My goal is to try to optimize this data flow.
State of art
I created a test Activity with some buttons for the main functions.
At class level I declared the objects that will be used:
private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = null;

These objects are initialized in the onCreate method
mBluetoothManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

The operations I perform are quite basic and work correctly.
I have a button to call startScan() on the mBluetoothLeScanner object.
I have another button to call stopScan().
In the onScanResult callback, I fill a HashSet of existing devices.
After stopping the scan I use a drop-down menu to show all discovered devices.
By tapping on an item, I start the connection with the selected BluetoothDevice.
device.connectGatt(activity, false, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);

Problems
When I connect, if the device sends the app an MTU exchange request then the app responds with 220. If on the device side this request is not executed, the app still sends a request with the value 220.
It therefore appears that, one way or another, a negotiation with an MTU size of 220 is exchanged during connection.
After connecting I receive the BluetoothGatt object directly from the callback:
onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)

If on this object I call
boolean result = gatt.requestMtu(512);

result is always true.
In any case in the callback
onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status)

the mtu value is always 220
Furthermore, on the device side, I can't find any trace of any new negotiations.
Questions time
Why does the app always return the value of 220?
How do I increase the value?
requestMtu(515) doesn't seem to work.
Note: I have used several tablets with Android 6, 8, 10, 12 and 14 but the exchanged value is always 220.
Does anyone have any idea what is happening and how it can be resolved?
Thank you all

Could this be the fault of your BLE device? An MTU request is simply a request, if the BLE device can only handle a value of 220 the result will always be 220 if requesting something bigger. Could you try to request something smaller, just to see if 220 is always the value or only the max value

@MichaelKotzjan, If I try with requests with lower values ​​(for example 180) then in the onMtuChanged(..) callback I find the MTU value set.
On the device side I can't find any trace of the request: as if everything was managed on the Android app side without sending anything. This is possible?

MTU negotiation always takes place between the two devices, so both devices are involved.

@Lipsyor as Emil already said, since it is a negotiation both devices need to be able to support the requested MTU. If one device can only support an MTU of up to 220 then that will be the maximum. Is this a custom BLE device where you have access to the source code?

@MichaelKotzjan, yes: is a custom BLE device. There is another team involved in the development. From my point of view I am pretty sure of the functioning of the Android app. But they tell me they haven't received any requests: I will insist to better check.
